# Generating html from tabular chat conversation data

Tags: html, r

I have this table of  chat conversation `mydf`

```
mydf = structure(list(User = c("Ana", "Ana", "Brian", "Ana", "Brian"), Message = c("Hi", 
"How are you?", "Good. You?", "Ok", "What's up?"), Time = structure(c(1512156236.17704, 
1512156238.67704, 1512156241.17704, 1512156243.67704, 1512156246.17704
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))), .Names = c("User", "Message", 
"Time"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

#> mydf
#   User      Message                Time
#1   Ana           Hi 2017-12-01 13:23:56
#2   Ana How are you? 2017-12-01 13:23:58
#3 Brian   Good. You? 2017-12-01 13:24:01
#4   Ana           Ok 2017-12-01 13:24:03
#5 Brian   What's up? 2017-12-01 13:24:06
```

My goal is to convert this data into conversation format in HTML. I am currently doing it by adding tags to the data and saving it. Then I have to work some more with CSS to make it better. Is there an easier way in R?

```
#REMOVE REPEATING NAMES
mydf$User = with(rle(mydf$User), unlist(sapply(seq_along(values),
                  function(i) c(rep(values[i], 1), rep("", lengths[i] - 1)))))

#ADD TAGS
mydf$User = ifelse(mydf$User == "", "", paste0("<h2 class=\"user\">", mydf$User, "</h2>"))
mydf$Message = paste0("<h3 class=\"msg\">", mydf$Message, "</h3>")
mydf$Time = paste0("<span class=\"tm\">", mydf$Time, "</span>")

#SAVE HTML    
writeLines(paste(paste(mydf$User, mydf$Message, mydf$Time), collapse = "\n"),"~/test.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this satisfies you, but I would go with an approach that extends the `data.frame` and writes it directly in the file

```
#REMOVE REPEATING NAMES
mydf$User = with(rle(mydf$User), unlist(sapply(seq_along(values),
              function(i) c(rep(values[i], 1), rep("", lengths[i] - 1)))))

#SAVE HTML    
write.table(
    data.frame(
        ifelse(mydf$User!="", "<h2 class=\"user\">",""), mydf$User, ifelse(mydf$User!="","</h2>",""),
        "<h3 class=\"msg\">", mydf$Message, "</h3>",
        "<span class=\"tm\">", mydf$Time, "</span>"),
    file = "~/test.html", quote = F, col.names = F, row.names = F )
```